# How do I check one index of list_a against every element in list_b, and repeat this process for all elements in list_a?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate through list_a so that each index in list_a is checked against every index in list_b. I have read about how to check lists against each other by index, but so far only understand how to iterate through the lists at the same time.

```
for i in range(list_a)
     if list_a[i] == list_b[i]
```

I considered using a while loop to use a single value of list_a and iterate through list_b

```
while i < len(list_b)
     for list_a[0] == list_b[i]

     for list_a[1] == list_b[i]
```

But if i write it like this then the index for a is manually determined and if it changes because the list it appended, which it needs to be elsewhere in my code, it will stop working. How can i use two separate counters so that i check each element of list_a against every element of list_b for every element of list_a. Could I use a counter?

The reason I want to write the code like this is to make sure I identify repeating elements in list_b and know every every location at which they exist.

Comment: here is a hint: `for i in list_a: print (i in list_b)`.

Comment: Have you considered using  [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) for doing this? You would be able to test what elements are equal or not equal between the two lists very efficiently this way...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check every element of list_a against every element in list_b you should use nested for

```
for el_a in list_a:
    for el_b in list_b:
        if el_a == el_b:
            # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Why wont this stop checking the lists against each other at the first value where 
el_a == el_b

Comment: No, only if you use a `break` after the if statement. If you want to check every element of a against every element of b you should do in this way